# how to solve $\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1+\frac{1}{3^{2i-1}})$?

Tags: calculus, limits

how to solve $\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{i=1}^n (1+\frac{1}{3^{2i-1}})$?

i’ve tried this:

let

$$
a_n= \prod_{i=1}^n (1+\frac{1}{3^{2i-1}})
$$

then

$$
lna_n=\sum_{i=1}^nln(1+ \frac{1}{3^{2i-1}})<\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^{2i-1}}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{3^{2n}}}{2}
$$

which means

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}lna_n<\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-\frac{1}{3^{2n}}}{2}=3/8
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n<e^{3/8}
$$

and

$$
lna_n=\sum_{i=1}^nln(1+ \frac{1}{3^{2i-1}})>\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+3^{2i-1}}=?
$$

but i don’t know how to sum up the right part of the inequation .

furthermore, even we got the number(wolframalpha told me is approximately 0.29) , the answer is 3/2, which means my solution is wrong at first, my solution only could prove the limit exists.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: For what it's wroth:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^{2i-1}} = 3\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^{2i}} = \frac{3}{3^2}\frac{1-\frac{1}{3^{2n}}}{1-\frac{1}{3^2}} = \frac{3}{8}(1-1/3^{2n})
$$ not what you got.

Comment: @ClementC. thanks i’ve fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Using the [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol) the infinite product is $(-\frac13,\frac19)_{\infty}\approx 1.389120.$ It does not have a simpler closed form and is probably a transcendental number.

Comment: thank you, what  you mean is the question could not be computed by hand?

Comment: It is for sure a trascendental number (ref. Takeuchi). @nevermind_15: what do you mean by *computed by hand*? Such product is just a constant like $e$or $\pi$, tailor-made techniques allow you to compute as many figures as you want.